# Google Play Store Campaign Measurement without EasyTracker?

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm trying to implement Google Play Store Campaign Measurement. 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/campaigns?hl=en#google-play-implement

In the samples Google use `EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(this)` and ...`activityStop(this)` to track the `start/stop` of an activity.

In my app I'm using just `Tracker` class, not `EasyTracker` for sending events. How I can track activity start/stop in this case? Tracker class doesn't have this functions and I don't understand what that functions actually do.

Comment: That is a good question... did you find an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Ha... just found the [answer...](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/screens#manual)

> **Manual Screen Measurement**
>
> You can also manually send a screen view by calling sendView(). Even
>   if you're already using EasyTracker's automatic screen measurement,
>   you can manually send screen views to measure user engagement with
>   Fragments or other content that might not be an Activity.
>
> sendView() is usually called in the onStart() callback of an Activity
>   or Fragment as win the following example:

```
/**
 * Within an Activity or Fragment
 */
@Override
public void onStart() {
  super.onStart();
  ... // Your other onStart() code.
  myTracker.sendView("Home Screen"); // Where myTracker is an instance of Tracker.
}
```